# adding custom information in chart via matplotlib using python

Tags: matplotlib

I'm able to draw / plot the data in to the chart.
What i want to know is there any way we can add custom information in the chart ?

Below is the image for reference (where An arrow and text shown in blue circle needs to be added in chart):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to use [matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-annotate) with a suitable [arrow style](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/fancyarrow_demo.html#annotation-arrow-style-reference) and annotation_clip argument set to `False`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plot curves
curve_A = [6, 4, 2, 8]
curve_B = [12, 3, 1, 9]
x = range(len(curve_A))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(curve_A)
ax.plot(curve_B)

# make sure the curves "touch" the axes on the left
ax.set_xlim(x[0])

# get all limits 
x_min, x_max = ax.get_xlim()
y_min, y_max = ax.get_ylim()

# define the annotation offset from the minimum x to the left
offset = 0.2

# annotate the first y-value of the curve A, placing the text below
ax.annotate("\nText A", (x_min - offset, curve_A[0]), (x_min - offset, y_min),
            xycoords='data', textcoords='data',
            size='large', color='k',
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='top',
            arrowprops=dict(
                arrowstyle='<->',
                shrinkA=0,
                shrinkB=0
            ),
            annotation_clip=False  # required to see the annotation outside of the axes
            )

# annotate the first y-value of the curve B, placing the text above
ax.annotate("Text B\n", (x_min - offset*2, y_min), (x_min - offset*2, curve_B[0]),
            xycoords='data', textcoords='data',
            size='large', color='k',
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom',
            arrowprops=dict(
                arrowstyle='<->',
                shrinkA=0,
                shrinkB=0
            ),
            annotation_clip=False  # required to see the annotation outside of the axes
            )
        
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]